# How To Delete an Azure Devops Release which is showing as Deployed - Error VS402946

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to delete a Release from a Legacy release Pipeline but when selecting the `Delete` option I get the following error...

```
VS402946: 'My-Release-2022-01-06' cannot be deleted as it is currently deployed on stage(s) Staging.
```

This is nonsense in "real world" as this Release pipeline has since been replaced with another pipeline so this isn't deployed anywhere anymore.

This was a badly generated release - I don't want to remove the pipeline for legacy tracking reasons. Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three steps when you have an older release def you need to delete and it was previously deployed.

1. Edit the definition, and delete all the environments.
2. create an environment with a default name that is different than the original and save.
3. Delete the environment as it will not see it as a valid deployment.

Comment: I don't want to mess with the definition really as it holds our deployment history. This does give me an idea though - I could try deleting the non-production environments from the definition and see if that frees anything up!

Comment: The above worked. By deleting the non-production environments from the definition I was then able to delete the bad releases from history that didn't get that far.